# Failed to find subscription in azure gov region

Tags: azure-gov

I am trying to query for a resource group's location and fail. This is done in an azure government region.
The response I get is the subscription does not exist.
The uri I am accessing is management.azure.com.

I am not using a sdk.

I did not see a corresponding remapping to another uri for gov regions. Is this the correct uri?

Thank you

Comment: What URL are you using? You're not using an SDK - how are you doing this? straight HTTP call? Endpoints listed in developer docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-developer-guide

Comment: We needed to implement it ourselves (c++).